# Implicits using structural types

Tags: scala

What is a convenient way to use implicit values that are simple types? Ideally, I would like to do something like this:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

type A = String
type B = String
implicit val a: A = "a"
implicit val b: B = "b" 
def c(implicit ab: A) = println(ab)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined type alias A
defined type alias B
a: A = a
b: B = b
c: (implicit ab: A)Unit

scala> c
<console>:13: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value a in object $iw of type => A
 and value b in object $iw of type => B
 match expected type A
```

One can't subclass final case classes like String or Long either

```
scala> class C extends String
<console>:11: error: illegal inheritance from final class String
       class C extends String
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `:paste`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Tim is correct, his approach would create a wrapper around the string and thus introduce runtime overhead. We can let the compiler do all this without the need to create new objects with a technique called type tagging. Following code is shamelessly taken from the [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) source:

```
trait Tagged[U] 
type @@[+T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

class Tagger[U] {
  def apply[T](t : T) : T @@ U = t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]
}

def tag[U] = new Tagger[U]
```

With those definitions you can write the following:

```
trait A
trait B

implicit def a: String @@ A = tag[A]("foo")
implicit def b: String @@ B = tag[B]("bar")

def foo(implicit a: String @@ A) = a.toString
def bar(implicit b: String @@ B) = b.toString

scala> foo
res21: String = foo

scala> bar
res22: String = bar
```

Comment: it's worth to mention about the unresolved [problems](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5183) between tags and the copmiler

Answer (score 2):

When you use "type" you're defining an alias for a type, not an actual new type.

What you want to do is define an actual new type.

```
case class A(a: String)
case class B(b: String)

implicit val a = A("a")
implicit val b = B("b")

def c(implicit ab: A) = println(ab.a)
```